# font-family is inherit. How to find out the font-family in chrome developer pane?

Tags: css, google-chrome, font-family

In the Chrome's developer pane, I can see these css settings of an element.

[image]

As far as I can see, every single `font-family` value is **inherit**.

How can I find what is the actual value of the font family? And how can I trace the definition of the root font-family value come from the inheritance hierarchy?

Comment: If any property for the `html` selector is `inherit`, that just means to use the user preferences (from the settings). The value will only change after you give something a value explicitly in a stylesheet. Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`Developer Tools > Elements > Computed > Rendered Fonts`

The picture you attached to your question shows the `Style` tab. If you change to the next tab, `Computed`, you can check the Rendered Fonts, that shows the actual font-family rendered.

[image: Developer Tools > Elements > Computed > Rendered Fonts]

Answer (score 10):

The [`inherit` value](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#value-def-inherit), when used, means that the value of the property is set to the value of the same property of the parent element. For the root element (in HTML documents, for the `html` element) there is no parent element; by definition, the value used is the initial value of the property. The initial value is defined for each property in CSS specifications.

The [`font-family` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#propdef-font-family) is special in the sense that the initial value is not fixed in the specification but defined to be browser-dependent. This means that the browser’s default font family is used. This value can be set by the user.

If there is a continuous chain of elements (in the sense of parent-child relationships) from the root element to the current element, all with `font-family` set to `inherit` or not set at all in any style sheet (which also causes inheritance), then the font is the browser default.

This is rather uninteresting, though. If you don’t set fonts at all, browsers defaults will be used. Your real problem might be different – you seem to be looking at the part of style sheets that constitute a browser style sheet. There are probably other, more interesting style sheets that affect the situation.

Answer (score 4):

Your browser's default font-family will be inherited for that case.

You can check the browser default font in chrome: 
**Settings > Web content > Customize fonts...**

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think op wants to know what the font that is used on a webpage is, and hoped that info might be findable in the 'inspect' pane.

Try adding the Whatfont Chrome extension.